# How to echo javascript code in php

Tags: php, javascript, echo

I am having a problem with how to echo javascript in php. I have a form which on submit will execute itself and echo some text and will redirect to a page in 5secs. I am currently echoing this:

```
header("Refresh: 5;url=index2.php?ID=".$objResult["ID"]."");

echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';
echo '<title>Klant toevoegen</title>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';
echo '<fieldset>';
echo ''.$Naam.' is added to the database, u will be redirected in a couple of seconds.<br><br>';
echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</body>';
echo '</html>';
```

The javascript I have is a countdown which counts down from 5 to 1. The code is this:

```
<script>

var countdownFrom = 5;  // number of seconds
var countdownwin;

var stp;
function CountDownStart() {
 stp = setInterval("CountDownTimer('CountDownTime')",1000)
}

function CountDownTimer(id)
{
if (countdownFrom==0) {clearInterval(stp); window.close(); }
else     {
            var x
            var cntText = "Closing in "+countdownFrom+" seconds";

        if (document.getElementById)
    {
        x = document.getElementById(id);
        x.innerHTML = cntText;        }
    else if (document.all)
    {
        x = document.all[id];
        x.innerHTML = cntText;        }
    }
countdownFrom--
}

</script>
   <title>Untitled</title>
</head>

<body onload="CountDownStart()">

<Div id="CountDownTime"></div>

</body>
```

Now I would like to echo this countdown script to replace the `<fieldset>` in the html. I have tried several things like just add the whole code in 1 `echo '';` and I tried to echo all the lines seperately but with both it crashes my whole script. If anyone knows how to do this it would be great!

Comment: ...and what is the *problem* you have?

Comment: @deceze The problem is that I can't get this to work. With the things I've tried it crashes my script.

Comment: "Crashes" how? Errors? What errors? Also, why are you 'echo'ing all this stuff? Just break out of PHP and write it plainly.

Comment: It wouldn't open the page in browser but you were right about breaking out of php and write it normally there. I did try that before but for some reason it didnt work back then. Thnx anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Wouldn't write all those echo's, instead, leave all the HTML and JS outside the PHP block

```
<?php
some php code
?>

HTML AND JS

<?php
More php if required
?>
```

And use

```
<?=$Naam?>
```

To inject your values where required

Alternatively you should look into template engines

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
echo <<<EOT
   /*  some text here */
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the script in a separate .js file  and `echo` the script tag:

```
<? echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/script.js' ></script> ?>
```

Don't forget to remove any HTML tags from the JS file, like `<body>`, `<head>`, etc.